# Cannot boot Ubuntu after installing Windows 10 using GRUB (boot-rapair did not help)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I installed Xubuntu 18.04 and decided to install Windows 10 afterwards (because I needed some features of Windows). I tried to install GRUB from live CD after installing Windows using boot-repair, but this did not solve my problem. GRUB just doesn't appear at the startup and Win 10 will be booted immediately.

The pastebin can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/S7QJxjYRcy/
The Laptop is a little bit oudated and still uses BIOS.

Thank you for your support!